# Find free number in a range

Tags: powershell

I have a range of numbers (say, 20-100). Lets say the following are occupied: 20, 21, 22, 24. 25, 26, 28.

I ask the user how many free numbers he wants. Lets say, he says three numbers. So my output should be 23, 27, 29.

How can I quickly do this with powershell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
$range = 20..100
$occupied = 20,21,22,24,25,26,28
$range | where-object {$occupied -notcontains $_} | `
select-object -first (read-host -Prompt "How many free numbers do you need?")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `Compare-Object` cmdlet:

```
compare $range $occupied -PassThru

23
27
29
30
31
...
100
```

Comment: I know this is soooo old but jon Z's answer is more accurate. Shay Levy's is more concise. Either way, this came in handy.